# Remote Tunnels access to localhost

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just found out about the new and awesome remote tunnels feature in VS Code. I have got it up and running. I was using Remote SSH a lot in the past and with Port Forwarding I could easily access the localhost of the remote machine. How do I access the localhost-url of my web application with remote tunnels?